# Firebase Emulator Times Out with import of large production data

Tags: firebase, firebase-cli

I am now using firebase emulator to speed local production and its awesome. However, I was trying to export production data (which was successful) and then import it using `firebase emulators:start --import ../backup/000 -P project-name`. It appears to start off great but then I get:

`Error: TIMEOUT: Port 8000 on localhost was not active within 30000ms`

Thoughts? Is there a parameter I am missing? The data I'm trying to use to test against is 1.5 GB.

Comment: I have the same issue! I think all we need is just a timeout configuration to extend that 30 sec to maybe 5 mins (The Code is here - https://github.com/firebase/firebase-tools/blob/66447909ab6f2defd04b257b48193c70d778c7ea/src/emulator/portUtils.ts#L142)